# Minecraft Server keeps overloading, showing an error message: "Can't keep up! Is the server overloaded? Running XXXXms or XX ticks behind"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

I am trying to optimize a modded *Minecraft* server and have had little luck in determining what could be causing the issues.

Here is the issue I am facing, every so often the server will hang up for a second. After the second, everything goes back to normal before it does it again. Picture of the error message:

> Can't keep up! Is the server overloaded? Running XXXXms or XX ticks behind

[image: screenshot of error message]

The *Minecraft* instance is modded with Fabric and 271 mods, ranging from adding new blocks to adding new mechanics. I will provide a list at the end.

I read online some methods to check for latency and those included using spark and carpet. I attached the spark information below.

[image: Spark details]
[image]

I found that for the most part, everything appears to be in the green except for max MSPT which is ludicrously high. When tracking server activity, I see these gradual rises in RAM before peaking and dropping back down. To try and prevent these spikes, I have added in tons of optimization mods but none seem to have resolved the issue. From Spark, it showed that the mods that utilized the most ms in tics were Lithium, modernfix, and c2m.

The server uses the following command to be loaded:

```
java -Xmx6G -Xms6G -XX:+UseG1GC -jar fabric-server-launch.jar nogui
```

I set the view distance to 25, and the simulation distance to 8.

Here is the list of mods:

```
Optimization mods
c2me-fabric-mc1.20.4-0.2.0+alpha.11.58.jar
Carpet-AMS-Addition-mc1.20.4-v2.33.1.jar.disabled
carpet-extra-1.20.3-1.4.128.jar.disabled
carpet-fixes-1.20-1.17.0.jar
carpet-tis-addition-mc1.20.4-v1.57.0.jar.disabled
CarpetTCTCAddition-all-2.2.212+46263e3-stable.jar.disabled
fabric-carpet-1.20.3-1.4.128+v231205.jar
ferritecore-6.0.3-fabric.jar
krypton-0.2.6.jar
letmedespawn-fabric-1.20.x-1.2.0.jar
lithium-fabric-mc1.20.4-0.12.1.jar
memoryleakfix-fabric-1.17+-1.1.5.jar
modernfix-fabric-5.14.0+mc1.20.4.jar
starlight-1.1.3+fabric.f5dcd1a.jar
servercore-fabric-1.4.0+1.20.3.jar
noisium-1.0.2+mc1.20.x.jar

Added mods
(Fabric)Chiseled-Bookshelf-Visualizer-1.20-2.0.jar
(Fabric)SculkHorn-1.20.4-1.5.jar
ACE-2.0.6.jar
adastra-fabric-1.20.4-1.16.5.jar
AdditionalAdditions-6.1.0.jar
AdditionalStructures-1.20.x-(v.4.2.1).jar
AirHop-v20.4.1-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
alloy-forgery-2.1.3+1.20.3.jar
animal_feeding_trough-1.0.3+1.20.4.jar
anvilrestoration-1.20.4-2.2.jar
architectury-11.1.17-fabric.jar
ArmorStatues-v20.4.0-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
AxesAreWeapons-1.7.3-fabric-1.20.2.jar
azaleawood-2.2.0-1.20.4.jar
BagOfHolding-v20.4.1-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
balm-fabric-1.20.4-9.0.6.jar
BarteringStation-v20.4.1-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
basicweapons-fabric-mc1.20.4+1.2.0.jar
bclib-3.30.1.jar
beautifiedchatserver-1.20.4-2.4.jar
BedrockTools-fabric-1.0.4.jar
better-end-4.30.1.jar
better-nether-9.30.0.jar
betterarcheology-1.1.6-1.20.4.jar
betterendcitiesbetterend-1.20.4.jar
betterloot-1.0.0+mc1.20.4.jar
bettermaps-mc1.20-0.5.2.jar
betterspawnercontrol-1.20.4-4.4.jar
BetterThanMending-fabric-2.0.0.jar
BetterTridents-v20.4.0-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
blastingraw-1.20.4-1-fabric.jar
blastingsand-1.20.4-11-fabric.jar
BlockRunner-v20.4.1-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
boatism-0.1.1.jar
BOMD-1.8.2-1.20.4.jar
Bookshelf-Fabric-1.20.4-23.0.6.jar
BotanyPots-Fabric-1.20.4-16.0.3.jar
BotanyTrees-Fabric-1.20.4-12.0.3.jar
botarium-fabric-1.20.4-3.0.8.jar
bottledair-1.20.4-2.3.jar
bottleyourxp-1.20.4-3.3.jar
bringbackluck-0.0.7-1.19.3-1.20.2.jar
bringdecay-0.0.3-1.20.2-1.20.4.jar
BuildingWands-mc1.20.4-2.6.9-release.jar
CameraJavaPort.jar
cardinal-components-api-5.4.0.jar
catloaf-1.1.0-1.20.4-FABRIC.jar
CerbonsAPI-Fabric-1.20.4-1.1.1.jar
chalk-2.2.3.jar
chalk-colorful-addon-2.1.1.jar
charmofundying-fabric-7.1.0+1.20.4.jar
cinderscapes-4.2.0.jar
clayblasting-1.20.4-0-fabric.jar
cloth-config-13.0.121-fabric.jar
Clumps-fabric-1.20.4-15.0.0.2.jar
collective-1.20.4-7.40.jar
ColoredLamps-fabric-mc1.20.4-1.0.1.jar
CombatNouveau-v20.4.5-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
conduitspreventdrowned-1.20.4-3.6.jar
cookingforblockheads-fabric-1.20.4-18.0.4.jar
copper-horns-1.0.3.jar
craftedcore-3.1.2-fabric.jar
craftingtweaks-fabric-1.20.4-20.0.3.jar
cristellib-1.2.4-fabric.jar
crossbow_expansion-1.20.4-1.2.1.jar
cryingghasts-1.20.4-3.3.jar
cryingportals-1.20.4-2.7.jar
ctov-3.4.2.jar
Debugify-1.20.4+1.0.jar
decorative-ladders-1.1.0.jar
deeperdarker-fabric-1.20.4-1.2.6.jar
disenchanter-0.1.9+1.20.3.jar
dismountentity-1.20.4-3.2.jar
DistractingTrims-Fabric-1.20.4-5.0.2.jar
dragondropselytra-1.20.4-3.3.jar
DramaticDoors-NeoQuiFabrge-1.20.4-3.2.0.jar
dungeons-and-taverns-3.1.1.jar
dungeons-and-taverns-swamp-hut-rework-1.1.jar
EasyAnvils-v20.4.3-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
EasyMagic-v20.4.0-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
EasyShulkerBoxes-v20.4.1-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
eden-ring-0.6.40.18.jar
elementalenchantments-1.1.0.jar
elytratrims-fabric-2.0.3+1.20.4.jar
elytratrims_extensions-fabric-2.0.0.jar
elytra_trinket-1.0.5.jar
enchantmentcompat-1.4.0+1.20.3.jar
endportalrecipe-1.20.4-5.2.jar
epileson-fabric-1.0.0+1.20-1.20.4.jar
ExplorersCompass-1.20.4-2.2.3-fabric.jar
extraalchemy-fabric-1.20.4-1.11.3.jar
extractpoison-1.20.4-3.3.jar
fabric-api-0.96.4+1.20.4.jar
fabric-cloaking-3.0.0-1.20.3.jar
fabric-language-kotlin-1.10.19+kotlin.1.9.23.jar
FauxCustomEntityData-fabric-1.20.4-9.0.1.jar
flight-affinity-1.0.3.jar
followersteleporttoo-1.20.4-2.4.jar
ForgeConfigAPIPort-v20.4.3-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
formations-1.0.2-fabric-mc1.20.4.jar
formationsnether-1.0.2.jar
formationsoverworld-1.0.1.jar
FriendlyFire-Fabric-1.20.4-21.0.3.jar
friendsandfoes-beekeeperhut-fabric-mc1.20.4-2.0.0.jar
friendsandfoes-fabric-mc1.20.4-2.0.10.jar
friendsandfoes-flowerymooblooms-fabric-mc1.20.4-2.0.1.jar
furnacerecycle-1.20.4-2.2.jar
geckolib-fabric-1.20.4-4.4.2.jar
GildedSherds-Fabric-1.20.4-4.0.2.jar
glide-1.0.1.jar
globalxp-fabric-1.20.4-1.10.4.jar
Glow Ink Plus Mod-fabric-1.20.4-1.2.jar
glowingbanners-1.3.2.jar
goldenfood-1.20.4-fabric-2.0.1.jar
growmeal-fabric-1.1.0.jar
guardvillagers-2.0.9-1.20.4.jar
HangGlider-v20.4.1-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
hardcorerevival-fabric-1.20.4-14.0.2.jar
healingcampfire-1.20.4-5.3.jar
HopoBetterMineshaft-[1.20.2-1.20.4]-1.2.1.jar
HopoBetterRuinedPortals-[1.20.2-1.20.4]-1.3.9.jar
HopoBetterUnderwaterRuins-[1.20.2-1.20.4]-1.1.5.jar
HorseBuff-1.20.2-2.1.3.jar
IllagerInvasion-v20.4.1-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
indypets-1.3.3-1.20.1.jar
inventoryessentials-fabric-1.20.4-10.0.3.jar
InventorySorter-1.9.0-1.20.4.jar
inventorytotem-1.20.4-3.2.jar
ironbookshelves-1.20.4-1.2.6-fabric.jar
IronDoorKey-FABRIC-1.20.4-1.0.jar
ironladders-1.20.4-2.1.50-fabric.jar
justmobheads-1.20.4-7.6.jar
justplayerheads-1.20.4-3.6.jar
lavender-0.1.4+1.20.3.jar
life-crystals-1.0.2+1.20.4.jar
litematica_wand.jar
lithostitched-fabric-1.20.4-1.1.5.jar
magiclib-all-0.7.398+fe2125a-stable.jar.disabled
MagnumTorch-v20.4.0-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
mcpitanlib-2.2.3-1.20.4-fabric.jar
mcw-trapdoors-1.1.2-mc1.20.4fabric.jar
MeleeExMachina_2.0-1.20.1Fabric.jar
MetalBundles-v20.4.2-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
midnightlib-fabric-1.5.3.jar
miners-compass-1.0.0+1.20.1.jar
mixintrace-1.1.1+1.17.jar
modern-glass-doors-5.3.0+1.20.3-and-later.jar
modification-of-critical-hit-1.3-1.20.1~2.jar
moonlight-1.20.4-2.10.3-fabric.jar
mooshroomtweaks-1.20.4-3.4.jar
moreberries-1.5.9.jar
more_fossils-2.0.0.jar
moveboats-1.20.4-3.2.jar
moveminecarts-1.20.4-3.4.jar
mru-0.4.0+1.20.4.jar
mythicmetals-0.19.5+1.20.4.jar
mythicupgrades-2.4.2+mc1.20.4.jar
nametagtweaks-1.20.4-3.3.jar
NaturesCompass-1.20.4-2.2.3-fabric.jar
nether-chest-mc1.20.3-5.2.jar
netheriteextras-0.2.2+mc1.20.1.jar
netherportalfix-fabric-1.20.4-15.0.1.jar
netherrackblasting-1.20.4-0-fabric.jar
nocturnal-bats-1.0.0+1.19.4.jar
nohostilesaroundcampfire-1.20.4-5.9.jar
OhMySherd-Fabric-1.20.4-4.0.2.jar
overworldpiglins-1.20.4-1.4.jar
owo-lib-0.12.5+1.20.3.jar
packedup-1.0.30c-fabric-mc1.20.4.jar
passiveshield-1.20.4-3.4.jar
pathunderfencegates-1.4.0+mc1.20.x.jar
pet-armor-1.2.2-1.20.X.jar
pizzas-1.1.4.jar
portablecrates-fabric-2.0.2+1.20.3-1.20.4.jar
portal-linking-compass-fabric-1.0.1+mc1.20.jar
pottery-1.0.1-fabric-mc1.20.4.jar
PureAmethystTools-v2.0.1-1.20.1-Fabric.jar
PureDiscsTrailsTales-v1.0.0-1.20.1-Fabric.jar
PureEmeraldTools-v3.0.0-1.20.1-Fabric.jar
PuzzlesLib-v20.4.36-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
qu-enchantments-1.3.8-1.20.4.jar
redstonepen-1.20.4-fabric-1.8.29.jar
reinforced-barrels-2.4.2+1.20.jar
reinforced-chests-2.4.4+1.20.jar
reinforced-shulker-boxes-2.5.2+1.20.jar
reinforced_deepslate-1.0.jar
resourcefulconfig-fabric-1.20.4-2.4.5.jar
resourcefullib-fabric-1.20.4-2.4.10.jar
RespawningAnimals-v20.4.0-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
RingsOfAscension-1.20.4-2.0.3.jar
sawmill-1.20.4-1.3.1-fabric.jar
scaffoldingdropsnearby-1.20.4-3.2.jar
scorched-1.1.3e.jar
sculk_depths-1.20.4-0.0.10-b.jar
SherdDuplication-Fabric-1.20.4-5.0.2.jar
sherdsapi-fabric-1.20.4-4.1.2.jar
SimpleRadio-fabric-1.20.2-2.2.4.jar
SimplySulphur-1.0_1.20-Fabric.jar
skeletonhorsespawn-1.20.4-3.8.jar
smallernetherportals-1.20.4-3.6.jar
smelting-plus-1.0.6.jar
smeltingstone-1.20.4-0-fabric.jar
snowballsfreezemobs-1.20.4-3.3.jar
SnowUnderTrees-2.2.0+1.20.4.jar
spark-1.10.58-fabric.jar
spawnermod-1.20.4-1.2.5+Fabric.jar
stacked-armor-trims-1.3.0-1.20.4.jar
Stoneworks-v20.4.0-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
StrawStatues-v20.4.0-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
stroopwafel-0.1-1.20.1.jar
supermartijn642configlib-1.1.8a-fabric-mc1.20.2.jar
supermartijn642corelib-1.1.17-fabric-mc1.20.3.jar
sushimod-v1.0.12-fabric-1.20.4.jar
SwordBlockingMechanics-v20.4.1-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
tectonic-fabric-1.20-v2.2.1.jar
Terralith_1.20.4_v2.4.11_FABRIC.jar
terrestria-6.2.0.jar
the_bumblezone-7.3.17+1.20.4-fabric.jar
The_Graveyard_3.2_(FABRIC)_for_1.20.4.jar
things-0.3.4+1.20.3.jar
toggleableitemframes-4.1.0-1.20.4.jar
toms_storage_fabric-1.20.4-1.6.11.jar
toms_trading_network-fabric-1.20.4-0.2.10.jar
torchhit-1.20.4-6.0.2.0-fabric.jar
totw_modded-fabric-1.0.3-1.20.1.jar
travelers-backpack-1.20.4-9.4.0.jar
trinkets-3.8.1.jar
triqueapi-1.1.1+mc1.20.4.jar
t_and_t-1.12.1.jar
UndergroundBunkers-1.0.3-1.19.2-1.20.4-fabric.jar
UniversalBoneMeal-v20.4.2-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
useful-mobs-2.2.jar
UsefulFood_Reborn-1.1.1-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
vanilla_plus-1.20.4-0.5.8.jar
variantbeehives-1.2.jar
variantchests-1.4.5.jar
variantcraftingtables-6.3.5+1.20.4.jar
vcinteraction-fabric-1.20.4-1.0.6.jar
veinmining-fabric-3.0.1+1.20.4.jar
VisualWorkbench-v20.4.1-1.20.4-Fabric.jar
voicechat-fabric-1.20.4-2.5.8.jar
walkers-3.2-fabric.jar
wardentools-2.4.0+mc1.20.4.jar
waystones-fabric-1.20.4-16.0.4.jar
WilderWild-2.3.3-Fabric+1.20.4.jar
wooledboots-1.7-fabric-mc1.20.1.jar
wooltweaks-1.20.4-3.3.jar
wraith-waystones-3.3.2+mc1.20.4.jar
XaerosWorldMap_1.37.8_Fabric_1.20.4.jar
Xaeros_Minimap_23.9.7_Fabric_1.20.4.jar
xtraarrows-3.0.8-fabric-mc1.20.4.jar
yet-another-config-lib-fabric-3.3.2+1.20.4.jar
YungsApi-1.20.4-Fabric-4.4.2.jar
YungsBetterDesertTemples-1.20.4-Fabric-3.4.1.jar
YungsBetterDungeons-1.20.4-Fabric-4.4.1.jar
YungsBetterEndIsland-1.20.4-Fabric-2.4.0.jar
YungsBetterJungleTemples-1.20.4-Fabric-2.4.1.jar
YungsBetterMineshafts-1.20.4-Fabric-4.4.1.jar
YungsBetterNetherFortresses-1.20.4-Fabric-2.4.1.jar
YungsBetterOceanMonuments-1.20.4-Fabric-3.4.1.jar
YungsBetterStrongholds-1.20.4-Fabric-4.4.1.jar
YungsBetterWitchHuts-1.20.4-Fabric-3.4.1.jar
YungsBridges-1.20.4-Fabric-4.4.0.jar
YungsExtras-1.20.4-Fabric-4.4.0.jar
zombiehorsespawn-1.20.4-4.8.jar
[Fabric]backported_wolves-1.1.0-1.19.3-1.20.4.jar
```

Comment: Those "spikes" if I recall are normal.  Last time a ran a server completely unmodded it happens too. It's just the resources being used and recycled overtime.

Comment: I noticed this when doing test to try and find any particular mod that was stressing the server. thanks for confirming my thoughts. 

I seem to keep getting "overload server cannot keep up 4485ms or 22 tics behind" and I am trying to solve this major issue. I will update the question to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

I solved part of the issue. As you can see in the Spark overlay, the minecraft server is located on a 7200rpm 1tb harddrive. This was not fast enough for reading and writing. by moving over to an ssd, it mitigated many of the slowdown issues. I will have to stress test it by having more people play but for now, it looks to be good